# iOS different validating results when archiving with different device selected

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, validation

I'm developing an app supporting minimum iOS 6 using XCode 6.1.
When archiving and validating my app using XCode, I noticed the following difference:

- When having my iPhone 6 selected, then Product -> Archive -> Validate, I got validation faliure:
  [image]
  [image]
- But when having an iPod running iOS6 selected, then do the same thing, I passed validation:
  [image]
  [image]

My question is:

- What is the difference when having different devices selected then produce an archive?
- In my case, what should I do? Should I submit the archive with the one that passed the validation, or should I debug the one failed validation, then submit that one?

PS: my architecture setting:[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just found out why...

Because in my Architectures settings, I have `Build Active Architecture Only` set to `YES`, so when I have iPhone 6 selected when archiving, XCode only builds the architectures the iPhone 6 has. Setting `Build Active Architecture Only` to `NO` makes all builds the same, and the validation passes.